# Apache Zeppelin - how to implement the feature to export data

Tags: apache-zeppelin

in Default view there is a feature to export the Data as CSV.
The problem is that I want to implements this Feature for the Users, someone has an idea how can I do?

[Download the Data as CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnnTL.png)